# Running Windows 7 on Unsupported Motherboard

Tags: windows-7, performance, motherboard

I have an [Intel D915GAG](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/dsktpboards/d915gag) motherboard from Intel ([technical specifications](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/15197/eng/D915GAV_D915GAG_TechProdSpec.pdf)).  I installed Windows 7 on in before I realized that Intel does not support running Windows 7 on this motherboard.  In fact, according to Intel the motherboard only supports Windows XP.  But Windows 7 seems to run just fine.  A quick check of the Windows 7 system requirements appears to confirm that the motherboard with operate with Windows 7.

What am I in for in the way of performance?  Are there special drivers (unavailable from Intel) that provide enhanced performance, without which the motherboard will perform less than optimally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Windows 7 installed without any problems and there are no devices which are not working in the Device Manager, then I think you're fine.

The fact that Intel has not released any special drivers for this older motherboard is as easily explained by Windows 7 already including all the drivers necessary to use the chipsets on this board.

If it is working then it is working. No?

Comment: That's kinda what I thought.  Thanks for confirming.